# Weird (let) variable assignment behavior in node repl - can't assign values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Node v12.14.1 on Windows 10 in cmd.
When assigning the value of an undefined function to a variable:

```
let a = f();
```

I get:

```
Thrown:
ReferenceError: f is not defined
```

Which is fine. But when I try:

```
a = 2;
```

I now get:

```
Thrown:
ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

And when I try:

```
let a = 2;
```

I get:

```
Thrown:
SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
```

So, a variable declared using let, when assigned the value of an undefined function, has its identifier already declared, and is not defined, at the same time.
Is this intended? Am I missing something here? Is this a bug?
The same does not happen when using var in the undefined function assignment, or when not using anything (global variable).

Comment: You're not crazy, and it's not a bug, but it sure is weird. :)

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8309

Answer (score 7, accepted):

REPLs are funny, but no, this behavior isn't a bug, it is indeed per spec. It's something you couldn't see in a non-REPL environment, though.

A `let` statement creates a binding¹ upon entry to the scope where `let` appears, but doesn't initialize it (unlike `var`, which initializes it with `undefined`). (In the case of the REPL "entering the scope" is basically just before it executes the code you've given it.) The initialization happens when the initialization part of the `let` statement happens, later when you you reach that statement in the step-by-step execution.² In your code, though, you never reach that part of the statement, because when the initializer was evaluated, it threw an error.

At that point, there's nothing you can do with `a`, because it exists but isn't initialized (it's stuck in the [Temporal Dead Zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#temporal_dead_zone_tdz)), and the only thing that *could* have initialized it (the original `let a = f();` statement) failed and can't be run again.

The reason you can't see that in non-REPL code is that the error would take you out of the scope where `a` has been created but not initialized. Consider:

```
try {
    let a = f(); // ReferenceError
    // Execution in this block never continues
} catch {
    // Execution arrives here...but `a` is not in scope
}
```

Since the error exits the scope, you won't see this outside of a REPL. You could see the same error messages easily enough, by trying to use something before its `let x` or `const x` (or `class X`) is reached in the code execution, like this:

```js
a = 1;

let a;
```

or this:

```js
console.log(a);

let a;
```

...but you can't have that exact same situation.

---

¹ *binding* - an entry for the variable (and similar) in the execution context's [environment record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-environment-records)

² If the `let` statement doesn't have an initializer, `undefined` is used at this point.

Comment: FWIW, I go into bindings and how the new-style declarations (`let`, `const`, and `class`) work in Chapter 2 of my new book coming out in a couple of months. Links in my profile if you're interested.